# Calculate and add data in to input fields

Tags: javascript, html

SO i have this fields:

```
<input type="text" id="price" name="price"> 
<input type="text" id="taxpercentage" name="taxpercentage">
<input type="text" id="taxpaied" name="taxpaied">
<input type="text" id="totalprice" name="totalprice">
```

After I add the price and the tax percentage I want the taxpaied and totalprice field to be automatically filled with the calculated values.

ex: if price = 200 and taxpercentage = 24 then the last 2 fields should get filled with 48 and 248.

I think this is possible with javascript but i didn't find anything online.

Comment: THis is possible only .. what you tried still now?

Comment: where is your script? what have you tried?

Comment: do you have button to click with?or what trigger to show taxpaid and total price?

Answer (score 0):

try this one....

```
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" onchange="calculate()"> 
<input type="text" id="taxpercentage" name="taxpercentage" onchange="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="taxpaied" name="taxpaied">
<input type="text" id="totalprice" name="totalprice">
    <script>
        function calculate()
{
    var price=document.getElementById("price").value;
    var tax=document.getElementById("taxpercentage").value;  
        if(price == "" || tax =="")
        {
          return false;
        }
    var taxpaied=document.getElementById("taxpaied");
    var totalprice=document.getElementById("totalprice"); 
        taxpaied.value = (price/100)*tax;
        totalprice.value = (price * 1) + (taxpaied.value * 1);
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/KGP5M/1/

```
var price, taxpercentage;
var update = function(){
    if(price && taxpercentage){
        document.getElementById('taxpaied').value= price * taxpercentage / 100;
        document.getElementById('totalprice').value= price + price * taxpercentage / 100;

    }
}
document.getElementById('price').onchange= function() {price = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value); update();};
document.getElementById('taxpercentage').onchange = function() {taxpercentage = parseInt(document.getElementById('taxpercentage').value); update()};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, one of possible ways to do it using plain JS is :-

JS

```
function add(){ //function is called when input changes in the input field
var x=parseInt(document.getElementById("price").value); //parse the value in input as integer and assign it to variable x
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("taxpercentage").value);//get tax percentage value
document.getElementById("taxpaied").value=x*y/100; //calculate tax and assign to taxpaid field
document.getElementById("totalprice").value=x+x*y/100; //calculate total
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="0" onchange="add()"> 
<input type="text" id="taxpercentage" name="taxpercentage"  value="0" onchange="add()">
<input type="text" id="taxpaied" name="taxpaied">
<input type="text" id="totalprice" name="totalprice">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5MN6m/1/)

Note that the calculations inside the function can change , I have done my own as an example. You can change the inner working of the function once you get the values from .

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
 <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="price" name="price" onkeyup="val()" onblur="val()"> 
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="taxpercentage" name="taxpercentage"  onkeyup="val()" onblur="val()">
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="taxpaied" name="taxpaied">
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="totalprice" name="totalprice">

<script type="text/javascript">

    function val()
    {
        var price=parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
        var taxpercentage=parseFloat(document.getElementById("taxpercentage").value);
        if(document.getElementById("price").value!="" && document.getElementById("taxpercentage").value!="")
        {

            var taxpaied = (price/100)*taxpercentage;
            var toatl= price+taxpaied;
            document.getElementById("taxpaied").value=taxpaied.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("totalprice").value=toatl.toFixed(2);
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("taxpaied").value="";
            document.getElementById("totalprice").value="";
        }

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do This Way

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f5g4j/1/)

```
$("#price,#taxpercentage").keyup(function(){
var val=$("#price").val();
var Tax=$("#taxpercentage").val();
var Taxpaided=(val/100)*Tax;
$("#taxpaied").val(Taxpaided);
var Tot=parseInt(val)+Taxpaided;
$("#totalprice").val(Tot); 
});
```

Comment: this is not pure javascript

Comment: He wants pure JavaScript, not jQuery. Also you have mistake here, you need to parse number, because it is "text", so `var Tot = parseInt(val) + Taxpaided;`

Comment: @Aaron Did he mentioned anywhere about that output should be only in javascript .. ?

Comment: @Aaron We think jquery is also java script library. the asker didnot Mention i want solution only in Pure javascript(without library) so i giving a quick OP using Jquery.

Comment: @Aaron i already answer your question  jquery is also java script library. that means its also javascript. but anyhow nothing i gain fighting with you. so we Waiting for asker answer

Comment: @Neophyte c# is also c library, does that mean for c programming you answer in c# progrmming? and FYI i am not downvoter here...

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
**USING JQUERY** [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/J4V5C/10/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="price" name="price"> 
<input type="text" id="taxpercentage" name="taxpercentage">
<input type="text" id="taxpaied" name="taxpaied">
<input type="text" id="totalprice" name="totalprice">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("#taxpercentage").blur(function(){
    if($("#price").val())
    {
        var price =parseFloat($("#price").val()),
            tax =parseFloat($(this).val());
      var taxpaied = price * tax/100;
        $("#taxpaied").val(taxpaied);
       $("#totalprice").val(taxpaied+price);
    }
});
```

**USING JAVASCRIPT** [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/J4V5C/11/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="price" name="price"> 
<input type="text" id="taxpercentage" name="taxpercentage" onchange="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="taxpaied" name="taxpaied">
<input type="text" id="totalprice" name="totalprice">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function calculate()
       {
    var price=document.getElementById("price").value;
    var tax=document.getElementById("taxpercentage").value;  
        if(price && tax)
        {      
        var taxpaied=document.getElementById("taxpaied");
        var totalprice=document.getElementById("totalprice"); 
        taxpaied.value = (price/100)*tax;
        totalprice.value = (price * 1) + (taxpaied.value * 1);
        }
      }
```